# Run def in ruby program

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner in programming and wrote this little program:

Test.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

def parse_file 
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml"))
  parse_xml(doc)
end

def parse_xml(doc)
  doc.root.elements.each do |node|
    parse_tracks(node)
  end
end

def parse_tracks(node)
  if node.node_name.eql? 'kapitel'
    puts 'New Kapitel'
  end
end
```

I know how to execute this code:

```
ruby test.rb
```

But how can I call the def parse_file?

Comment: Put `parse_file` in the end of `test.rb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add whatever you want to the end of your file. Ruby scripts are simply scripts, they are being interpreted:

```
…
end

parse_file   # ⇐ HERE YOU GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either call the method at the end of your `test.rb` file:

```
def parse_file 
  # ...
end

parse_file
```

And run it with

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

Or leave the file as it is, require it as a library and call the method manually:

```
$ ruby -r test.rb -e "parse_file"
```

Rather than hard-coding your file path, you can pass it as an argument when calling your script. Arguments can be accessed via the [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) array:

```
def parse_file(file)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file))
  parse_xml(doc)
end

parse_file(ARGV.first)
```

Now you can run it with:

```
$ ruby test.rb test.xml
```

Another option is to make the script executable. Add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as the first line of you file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

And set the execute flag:

```
$ chmod +x test.rb
```

Now you can run it with:

```
$ ./test.rb test.xml
```

Comment: *+1* for this `$ ruby -r test.rb -e "parse_file"`. But the last part I didn't get. Any reference please?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world#Executable_Ruby_scripts

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
parse_file
```

in the end of your ruby file